# Hide first_name and last_name in Django's admin

Tags: django, django-admin

I don't like coercing a user's name into separate first_name and last_name fields, so I replaced user.first_name and user.last_name with profile.fullname.

It doesn't make sense to show all three names in the admin, so I tried this:

```
admin.site.unregister(User)

class ProfileInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Profile

class ProfileAdmin(UserAdmin):
    inlines = [ProfileInline]
    exclude = ('first_name', 'last_name')

admin.site.register(User, ProfileAdmin)
```

That doesn't work, and I can't tell why:

> Caught KeyError while rendering: "Key 'first_name' not found in Form"

Comment: Django's UserAdmin class uses 2 different forms, one for the 'add' view and one for 'change' view. Different fields are defined in each of them. Where does this error occurs exactly?

Comment: @rantanplan has a good point, this is probably appearing on the "add" page when django uses a form that only contains "username" and "password". I don't remember how this ModelAdmin dynamically switches forms but that would be my first guess. I'd go lookup UserAdmin to find the appropriate way to override one of the two forms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Refs [the code](https://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/contrib/auth/admin.py#L41), the `'last_name'` and `'first_name'` have already been declared in [`fieldsets`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.fieldsets). Then the error occurs because the layout declaration says there are `last_name` and `first_name` which can no longer be found in form fields. Override `fieldsets` will do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

```
class UserAdminCustom(UserAdmin):

    def get_fieldsets(self, request, obj=None):
        fieldsets = super().get_fieldsets(request, obj)
        new = []
        for name, fields_dict in fieldsets:
            if fields_dict['fields'] == ('first_name', 'last_name', 'email'):
                fields_dict['fields'] = ('email',)
            new.append((name, fields_dict))
        return new
```